# MediaPlayer doesn't send HTTP request?

Tags: android, http, sockets, media-player

I was trying to transfer a mp3 file to mediaplayer through socket. Here is the article I followed:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

I also add code for mediaplayer

```
SERVERADDRESS = "http://" + SERVERIP + ":"+Integer.toString(SERVERPORT);

public class MediaPlayerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(SERVERADDRESS);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("socketExample","Error! " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the connection is established, but I cannot get anything out of BufferedReader. Does this mean MediaPlayer doesn't send HTTP request? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I made a mistake. This is the way I launched the two services:

```
// start server
Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
serverThread.start();

// start mediaplayer
Thread mediaplayerThread = new Thread(new MediaPlayerThread());
mediaplayerThread.start();
```

It is totally wrong because mediaplayerThread may start before serverThread.